# How do I prove this is true? $A(j+x+x^2+....+x^n)= A(j-x{^{n+1}})(j-x){^{-1}} $

Tags: summation

How do I show that the following is true?

$$ A(j+x+x^2+....+x^n)= A(j-x{^{n+1}})(j-x){^{-1}} $$

I tried dividing both sides by $A$ and then multiplying by $(j-x)$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there because the $j$ is throwing me off. Usually it's a '$1$'.

Comment: Yeah this isn't true. I suggest multiplying both sides by $j-x$ and evaluate that big product to see how things play out.

Comment: If the identity is true for all $A,x$, then take $A=1,x=0$ and immediately get $j=1$.

Comment: The equation is not true if $j \neq 1$.  So, @CalvinKhor is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of the equation (not depending on $A$, because its value can be any), are:
$j=1$,

$j=\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x} $.

Verification for $j=$1, we take it for granted.

Verification for $j=\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x} $:

$A(j+x+x^2+....+x^n)= A(j-x{^{n+1}})(j-x){^{-1}}$,

$A(\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x}+ x+x^2+....+x^n)=\frac{A(\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x}-x^{n+1})}{\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x}-x}$,

$A(\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x}+ \frac{x(x^{n}-1)}{x-1})=\frac{A(\frac{x^{2}(x^{n}-1)}{1-x})}{ -\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x}+x}$,

$Ax=Ax$.

The assertion is true if

$j=1$,

and

$j=\frac{x(x^{n}-x)}{1-x} $.